# Select from a third table based upon a union result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently selecting Material from two tables using a `union` operator:

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT Material 
FROM (
       SELECT Material    
       FROM DP_Historical_Data 
       EXCEPT SELECT Material 
       FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem
     ) HD
 UNION SELECT Material 
 FROM (
        SELECT Material 
        FROM DP_Historical_Data_Archive 
        EXCEPT SELECT Material 
        FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem
      ) HDA
```

What I want to do now is use the retrieved Materials to get a description from a third table, i.e.:

```
Select MaterialDescription 
from Description_Table DT 
Where DT.Material = UnionResult.Material
```

Is there any tidy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select UnionResult.Material, DT.MaterialDescription 
FROM Description_Table DT 
JOIN
(    
    SELECT Material FROM 
    (
       SELECT Material 
       FROM DP_Historical_Data 
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT Material 
       FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem
    ) HD
    UNION 
    SELECT Material 
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT Material 
       FROM DP_Historical_Data_Archive 
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT Material
       FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem
    ) HDA
) UnionResult ON DT.Material = UnionResult.Material
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DT.MaterialDescription
FROM Description_Table DT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Material
    FROM (
        SELECT Material
        FROM DP_Historical_Data

        EXCEPT

        SELECT Material
        FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem
        ) HD

    UNION

    SELECT Material
    FROM (
        SELECT Material
        FROM DP_Historical_Data_Archive

        EXCEPT

        SELECT Material
        FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem
        ) HDA
    ) unires
WHERE DT.Material = unires.Material
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW UnionResult AS
    (
    SELECT Material FROM (SELECT Material FROM DP_Historical_Data EXCEPT SELECT Material
    FROM SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem) HD
    UNION 
    SELECT Material FROM
         (SELECT Material FROM DP_Historical_Data_Archive EXCEPT SELECT Material FROM 
          SAS_GLOBE_Material_to_SASBaseItem) HDA
    )

Select MaterialDescription from Description_Table DT,UnionResult
Where DT.Material = UnionResult.Material
```